# Can I list all items of an Azure table(Azure Table Storage) just by PartitionKey?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I tried to use the below uri for REST call, but getting error(403 Forbidden)

```
https://$storageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$tableName()?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'Key1'
```

Is there other way? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, we can use [share key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) to call the Azure table rest api

```
$accesskey="<storage account key>"
    $storageAccount = "<account name>"
    $version = "2017-04-17"
    $resource = "table name"
    $key="Jim"
   
    $table_url = "https://$storageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$($resource)?`$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'$($key)'"
    # create share key
    $GMTTime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddYears(1).toString('R')
    $stringToSign = "$GMTTime`n/$storageAccount/$resource"
    $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($accesskey)
    $signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign))
    $signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
    $headers = @{
        'x-ms-date'    = $GMTTime
        "Authorization"  = "SharedKeyLite " + $storageAccount + ":" + $signature
        "x-ms-version" = $version
        "Accept"         = "application/json"
    }
    $item = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $table_url -Headers $headers -ContentType application/json
    $item.value
```

### [image]

## Update

Regarding how to create sas token via Azure Portal, please refer to the following steps

1. Create sas token
   [image]
2. Test

```
 GET https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable()
?$filter=<>
&sv=2019-02-02&ss=t&srt=o&sp=r&se=2020-03-27T13:01:24Z&st=2020-03-27T05:01:24Z&spr=https&sig=OFUNXShu6kTojIp3SU...TkG%2BXAVZXJ8sqc%3D
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jim. It works fine with access key.

Currently I am using a SAS token, and the URI is not working with SAS. Could you please help me on that.
I have used the below format - 
$header2 = @{
        "x-ms-version" = '2017-04-17'
        'x-ms-date'    = $GMTTime;
        Accept = 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
    }
$tableUri2= "https://$storageAccount.table.core.windows.net/$tableName()?`$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'$($PartKey)'$sasToken"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $tableUri2 -Headers $header2 -ContentType application/json

Comment: @SouravKarmakar Could you please tell me how you create sas token? You can use PowerShell command `New-AzStorageAccountSASToken`.  For example, we can use the folloiwng script ``` New-AzStorageAccountSASToken  -Service Table -ResourceType Object -Permission "r"``` to generate sas token.

Comment: I have created the SAS token from Azure Portal. I provided it only 'Read' access to the table storage. Anyway, SAS token would be same if we generate it from PowerShell or Azure Portal.

Comment: @SouravKarmakar please check my update. Regarding how to create sas token, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas#account-sas-uri-example